Using Core ML in a .swiftpm file
I've been struggling for a few weeks to integrate my Core ML Image Classifier model into my .swiftpm project, and I’m hoping someone can help.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

I converted my .mlmodel file to .mlmodelc manually via the terminal.
In my Package.swift file, I tried both "copy" and "process" options for the resource.

The issues I’m facing:

When using "process", Xcode gives me the error:


"multiple resources named 'coremldata.bin' in target 'AppModule'."


When using "copy", the app runs, but the model doesn’t work, and the terminal shows:


"A valid manifest does not exist at path: .../Manifest.json."

I even tried creating a Manifest.json manually to test, but this led to more errors, such as:

"File format version must be in the form of major.minor.patch."
"Failed to look up root model."

To check if the problem was specific to my model, I tested other Core ML models in the same setup, but none of them worked either.
I feel stuck and unsure of how to resolve these issues.
